# Finding related images in the Amazon Product Advertising API 

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-product-api

Is there a way of requesting Related Images like the Amazon website shows of certain products? I wanted to get the images so that I can mirror the functionality in my own retail client. The Images response group doesn't seem to help.

like this one 
http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004SGLDM6/ref=s9_simh_gw_p21_d0_g21_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=179Q3KXHNZGJQSHFBGZ3&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294

Comment: I'm pretty sure the product advertising api will show the images.  It seems like you already have that in your title, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm using the Images ResponseGroup but it only returns 1 image in different sizes. wanted to know if there is any way of getting others.

Comment: Yes, you can get all images.  Include your code or what you are sending to the API and I can help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you are using the [Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html). If so, then you would need to ask for the [Images Response Group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html)

An example request would be:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AWSKEY&AssociateTag=ASSOCIATETAG&ItemId=B004SGLDM6&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2012-04-27T17%3A52%3A13Z&Version=2009-03-31&Signature=SIGNITURE
```

You would obviously need to put your key, tag, and signature in that last URL.

Comment: I'll put it up in the next comment